# GWT Reflection with deferred bindings GAE works in Firefox, not chrome, IE

Tags: gwt, deferred

i have a problem with deferred bindings.

i created it like in this Blog:
http://programmatica.blogspot.com/2007/10/classfornamefullyqualifiedclassnamenewi.html

My code crashed at "GWT.create". But only when i run it on Google App Engine, and only in IE and Chrome.
Code works correctly local in every browser and online on GAE in Firefox.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("AMsController");
               logger.log(Level.INFO, "start reflect");
final IPresenterFactory factory = (IPresenterFactory)     
GWT.create(IReflectiveFactory.class);
logger.log(Level.INFO, "1");
IDynamicPresenter p =  factory.newInstance("ch.zhaw.ams.module.football.sfv.news.client.presenter.NewsPresenter");
```

i don't have any error messages, but if I anlyse the cache.html for IE and for Firefox they are different.

it thows a ClassCast exception in IE, but not in firefox

Comment: "it breaks" is not an error message.

Comment: i cant evaluat an error message... :-/

Comment: Actually i'm trining to get the stack trace, but i don't get it on client side and no log entry on Google App Engine developer console.

Comment: If I compile the code without runtime class-casting the code works on App Engine as well as on local server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled it without Runtime Class-Casting - than it works!

problem was ClassCasting in IE-cache.html file

-XdisableCastChecking as Compiler Flag

I descibed it here
http://samuelschmid.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-generator-for-generic-class.html